# Metonym Confusion Redux

Tags: metonyms

It seems that I am once again confused about the finer points of metonyms. The example I give  my students is the phrase *Today, Ottawa announced...*, where *Ottawa* is a metonym for *the Canadian government* (because the two are closely-associated concepts).

But what about *They went to the bedroom and had a good time*? Is *to have a good time* a metonym for *to have sex* (aside from also being a euphemism)? Speaking of which—are euphemisms metonymic by definition (or at least a subset of metonymy)?

Also, I bought some sort of medicinal drink at Safeway yesterday and it's called "Hot Lemon Relief"—can *relief* be a metonym for *(medicinal) drink*?

Answer (score 2):

During a discussion of my question, I've been able to ferret out an answer:

1. As I already knew, the most basic example of **metonymy** is one idea that is closely associated with another, for instance, in *Washington made a decision*, *Washington* metonymically represents *the American Government*.
2. The problem, however, seems to be arise where the relationship between the two terms is not established by consensus well enough  or is slightly different than, as J.A. Cuddon defines it in *Literary Terms and Literary Theory*, "the name of an attribute or a thing is substituted for the thing itself" (510). Thus, in a product called "Hot Lemon Relief," *Relief* metonymically represents *medicinal drink*. However, to understand this representation fully, one would probably have to actually see the product packaging (whereas the previous example is underwritten by socio-cultural consensus).
3. Finally, I had wondered whether euphemisms are metonymic (or a subset of metonymy). BraddSzonye convinced me to the contrary in the example I proposed: in *They went to the bedroom and had a good time*, the association between *to have a good time* and *to have sex* is, more than anything else, idiomatic. There does seem to be some cross-over between epithet and metonym in one example I found, where the colour *red* is associated with *Communism* (e.g. *He's a red.*). However, any euphemistic/dysphemistic overtones would be idiomatic, once again.
4. On an unrelated note, in my research I have come across another very interesting figurative feature called *hypallage*, also known as *transferred epithet*, which semantically combines features of personification and metonymy. More information is available [here](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-transferred-epithet.htm) and [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/transferredepitheterm.htm).